# Invalid sObject type 'DataDotComEntitySetting'

Tags: trigger, unit-test, sobject, describesobject, data.com

We have Data.com, namespace jigsaw_clean, v 2.16.2 installed and I am encountering an sObject type error when I try to do a simple DML statement in a unit test script.  The test method instantiates a global method from another managed package (rh2) and then attempts to insert a bare bones Contact record.

The following is a snippet from the debug log for your reference:

> 15:11:47.071
>   (1071657000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[42]|system.Type.newInstance() 
>   15:11:47.071
>   (1071757000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[42]|system.Type.newInstance() 
>   15:11:47.071 (1071877000)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|rh2 
>  15:11:47.290
>   (1290890000)|DML_BEGIN|[1237]|Op:Insert|Type:rh2__Date_Sync__c|Rows:1
>   
>  15:11:47.347 (1347012000)|DML_END|[1237] 
>  15:11:47.347
>   (1347133000)|DML_BEGIN|[52]|Op:Insert|Type:Contact|Rows:1 
>   15:11:47.370 (1370901000)|DML_END|[52] 
>  15:11:47.370
>   (1370990000)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[52]|System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION,
>   INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'DataDotComEntitySetting' is not
>   supported.: []

We already run in a system context in the other managed package and exclude 'with sharing' in the class signatures.  This exception is not encountered in the unit test script if the DML is performed before the the global class is instantiated or if the global class is not included in the test script.

Has anyone else encountered this behavior before?  Any ideas or information to gather that will help us resolve or troubleshoot further?

Comment: Just thinking is this some custom setting you missed during deployments ?

Comment: Thank you for your idea.  The curious thing about this issue is that DataDotComEntitySetting is not used in the global class or unit test script.  May possibly be referenced in jigsaw_clean (already tried to utilize SF support without avail).  To help with the investigation, does anyone know of another way to contact support for the jigsaw_clean package?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I just ran into what might be a related situation.

Comment: Disabling the Clean Feature was the solution for me. Looks to be a Platform issue. I have started a case and have sent SFDC support links to these threads. My Issue: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9719/datadotcomentitysetting-is-not-supported/9721?noredirect=1#comment13811_9721