# 'DataDotComEntitySetting' is not supported

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I am writing a custom email service. I can get the incoming csv file and parse it down to rows and then columns. I do my thing, then I try to insert the objects (I know they are all original, the data has been de-duped already).

When I go to preform my insert, I get the following DML exception.

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. 
First exception on row 0; 
first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION,
INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'DataDotComEntitySetting' is not supported
```

What the heck is "**DataDotComEntitySetting**." I have no idea what that is or where I am using/setting it. Does it have to do with the fact that I am using sObject as the container? We do have Data.com setup in org.

I am sure I am just missing something....

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY HELP!

~Red

Here is the code that causes the above DML exception:

---

```
public static list<sObject> csvTosObject(List<List<String>> parsedCSV, string objectType){

    Schema.sObjectType objectDef = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectType).getDescribe().getSObjectType();
    system.debug('================================================================================== You want me to make a '+objectDef);

    list<sObject> objects = new list<sObject>();
    list<string> headers = new list<string>();

    for(list<string> row : parsedCSV)
    {
        for(string col : row)
        {
            headers.add(col);
        }
        break;
    }
    system.debug('================================================================================== File Column Headers');
    system.debug(headers);

    integer rowNumber = 0;
Integer rowCount = 0;

    for(list<string> row : parsedCSV)
    {
        if(rowNumber == 0)
        {
            rowNumber++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
 system.debug('================================================================================== Row Index: ' + rowNumber);
            sObject thisObj = objectDef.newSobject();
            integer colIndex = 0;
string headerName;
String ftoHeader;

            for(string col : row)
            {                   
ftoHeader = headers[colIndex].trim();
                      system.debug('================================================================================== Column Name ' + ftoHeader);

                if(ftoHeader.length() > 0){

                if(ftoHeader == 'ReferenceNumber'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Tracking_Number__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'SubmitDate'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Date_Received__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'FirstName'){
                headerName = 'FirstName';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'LastName'){
                headerName = 'LastName';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'JobFunction'){
                headerName = 'Role__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'JobTitle'){
                headerName = 'Title';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'CompanyName'){
                headerName = 'Company';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Email'){
                headerName = 'Email';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Phone'){
                headerName = 'Phone';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Fax'){
                headerName = 'Fax';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Address'){
                headerName = 'Street';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'City'){
                headerName = 'City';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'State'){
                headerName = 'State';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Country'){
                headerName = 'Country';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'ZipCode'){
                headerName = 'PostalCode';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'RequestType'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Inquiry_Type__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'ProductDescription'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Product__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'RequestSpecifics'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Specifics__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'PreferredContactMethod'){
                headerName = 'FTP_Contact_Method__c';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'Industry'){
                headerName = 'Industry';

}else if(ftoHeader == 'ProductDescription'){
                headerName = 'FTO_Content__c';

}else{
                headerName = 'NO';
system.debug('================================================================================== Skipping column '+ftoHeader);
                }                  

if( headerName != 'NO'){
system.debug('================================================================================== Adding to Object for insert');
try {                       
thisObj.put(headerName,col.trim());
system.debug('=================================================================================='+ftoHeader+' column mapped to ' + headerName);
                   }
                   catch(exception e){
                       system.debug('================================================================================== No corresponding SFDC field specified in header');                           
                   }
}
colIndex++;
                }
            } 
//Add to collection for processing
            objects.add(thisObj);
            rowNumber++;
rowCount++;
        }       
    }
try
{
    insert objects;
    system.debug('=================================================================================='+rowCount+' Records Inserted');
}
catch(exception e)
{
System.debug('================================================================================== insert FAILED');
}
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this very recent blog post](http://advancedapex.com/2013/03/13/anatomy-of-a-platform-bug/), this looks like a platform bug, the solution to which is

> turning off the "Clean" feature in data.com

Please leave a comment on this question, as well as [this earlier question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/invalid-sobject-type-datadotcomentitysetting), if that works. Apparently a few people have run into it.

Comment: PS - It's too bad though, we actually use the Clean feature...

Comment: File a Case on it anyway, that will help it get prioritized.

Comment: I did. Gave them links to this thread :)